# Не получается переделать рекурсивный алгоритм поиска всех путей в графе в итеративный

Tags: алгоритм, golang, рекурсия, графы

Здравствуйте! Есть рекурсивная функция поиска всех путей в графе:

```golang
func (this *Graph) FindPath(from Word, to Word, visited Dict, current Path) {
    if from.Eq(to) {
        if len(current) > this.Max {
            this.Max = len(current)
            fmt.Println(current)
        }

        this.Pathes = append(this.Pathes, current)
        return
    }

    if visited.Index(from) != -1 {
        return
    }

    index := this.nodes.Index(from)

    if index == -1 {
        return
    }

    for r := 0; r < len(this.rules); r++ {
        index := from.Index(this.rules[r].Pat)

        if index == -1 {
            continue
        }

        vis := make(Dict, len(visited))
        copy(vis, visited)
        vis = append(vis, from)

        cur := make(Path, len(current))
        copy(cur, current)
        cur = append(cur, this.rules[r])

        this.FindPath(from.ApplyRule(this.rules[r]), to, vis, cur)
    }
}
```

Я попытался переделать ее в итеративную:

```golang
func (this *Graph) FindPathes(from Word, to Word) {
    this.Pathes = make([]Path, 0)
    this.Max = 0

    nodes := stack.New()
    pathes := stack.New()
    visiteds := stack.New()

    nodes.Push(from)
    visiteds.Push(Dict{from})
    pathes.Push(make(Path, 0))

    for nodes.Len != 0 {
        curn := nodes.Pop().(Word)
        curp := pathes.Pop().(Path)
        curv := visiteds.Pop().(Dict)

        if curn.Eq(to) {
            if len(curp) > this.Max {
                this.Max = len(curp)
                fmt.Println(curp.ApplyVerbose(from))
            }

            this.Pathes = append(this.Pathes, curp)
            continue
        }

        for r := 0; r < len(this.rules); r++ {
            index := curn.Index(this.rules[r].Pat)

            if index == -1 {
                continue
            }

            newword := curn.ApplyRule(this.rules[r])

            if curv.Index(newword) != -1 {
                continue
            }

            newp := make(Path, len(curp))
            copy(newp, curp)
            newp = append(curp, this.rules[r])

            newv := make(Dict, len(curv))
            copy(newv, curv)
            newv = append(newv, newword)

            pathes.Push(newp)
            nodes.Push(newword)
            visiteds.Push(newv)
        }
    }
}
```

**stack** - самописная реализация стека, допустим, что там все правильно работает.

**Word** - `[]int`
**Dict** - `[]Word`
**Path** - `[]Rule`
**Rule** - `struct{Pat Word, Rep Word}`

**Index** - для `Dict` и `Path` возвращает индекс нужно элемента (или -1), а для `Word` - место начала подстроки (или -1).

**Word.Eq** - проверяет два слова на равенство.

Первая функция работает верно, а вторая не завершает работу за разумное время. Не могли бы вы помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом куске кода есть строчка:

```
index := this.nodes.Index(from)

if index == -1 {
    return
}
```

во втором ничего похожего нет. Нужно было добавить после объявления `newword` такое же условие:

```
if this.nodes.Index(newword) == -1 {
                continue
}
```

Теперь все работает. Важный момент: итеративная функция как минимум в три с лишним раза быстрее.